# Return first n non NaN value in python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nan

How do you get the first n elements of a list returned that are not nan values?

For example:

```
lst = [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

n = 3 

Output: [1,2,3]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `itertools.filterfalse()` together with `math.isnan()`:

```
import math, itertools
nan = float("nan")
lst = [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
list(itertools.islice(itertools.filterfalse(math.isnan, lst), 3))
```

Itertools usage is mainly an optimization and can be replaced with normal slicing:

```
[i for i in lst if not math.isnan(i)][:3]
```

As @Pranav emphasized in the comments, even if the first approach looks a bit more complicated, it prevents the whole list from being processed and stops as soon as the first 3 non-nan numbers are encountered. It is *much* more efficient when you have large lists.

Comment: The advantage of using the itertools approach is that your entire list doesn't need to be processed. The iterator only yields the first three. The slicing approach forces the entire list through the iteration and then slices. It's worth noting that the first approach is _much_ more efficient if you have a large list and only want the first three elements.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Emphasized accordingly :-)